# Get hours, minutes and seconds correctly

Tags: java, string, date, format

I had previously created a question about this but I am still having problems.

I want to create a cooldown for player challenges. Currently there are two types of cooldowns, DAILY and WEEKLY.

The Daily cooldown lasts from the time the challenge is completed until 23:59 of the day, that is if you complete it at 14:00 you would have to wait 9 hours for the challenge to be enabled again.

The weekly cooldown is the same but the challenge is enabled until Thursday night, then the remaining time would be until Thursday night

So I want to get the hours, minutes and seconds until the cooldown ends but I can't get it right, I get giant numbers or it just doesn't work. I have never worked with dates and times, this would be my first time.

When a challenge is completed I store the date and time it was completed, something like this: 10-12-2021 and 20:33:58. Then I get them in the code to calculate the remaining time but when I get the String I get "-1" something like: 7d 10623m 637385s or 1d 2753m 1935s

My code for Daily:

```
public String getDailyCountdown(UUID uuid, Quest quest) {

    QuestProperties questProperties = plugin.getQuestsCache().get(uuid, quest);

    String countdownTimePlaceholder = "";

    String[] completionDate = questProperties.getCompletionDate().split("-"), completionTime = questProperties.getCompletionTime().split(":");
    int completionDay = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[0]), completionMonth = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[1]), completionYear = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[2]);
    int completionHour = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[0]), completionMinutes = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[1]), completionSeconds = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[2]);
    LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(completionYear, completionMonth, completionDay, completionHour, completionMinutes, completionSeconds);
    LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 11, 25, 23, 59, 0);

    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long durationMillis = Duration.between(fromDateTime, toDateTime).toMillis();
    Duration duration = Duration.between(fromDateTime, toDateTime);
    long s = duration.getSeconds();
    long s2 = s * 1000L;
    long waitingTime = current - durationMillis;
    long div = waitingTime / 1000L;
    long waitingSeconds = s - div, waitingMinutes = waitingSeconds / 60L, waitingTimeHours = waitingMinutes / 60L;

    if (durationMillis + s2 > current && durationMillis != 0L) {

        if (waitingMinutes > 59L) waitingMinutes -= 60L * waitingTimeHours;

        if (waitingMinutes > 0L) countdownTimePlaceholder = waitingMinutes + "m" + countdownTimePlaceholder;

        if (waitingTimeHours > 0L) countdownTimePlaceholder = waitingTimeHours + "h" + countdownTimePlaceholder;

        return countdownTimePlaceholder;

    }
    return "-1";
}
```

My code for Weekly:

```
QuestProperties questProperties = plugin.getQuestsCache().get(uuid, quest);
    String countdownTimePlaceholder;
    String[] completionDate = questProperties.getCompletionDate().split("-"), completionTime = questProperties.getCompletionTime().split(":");
    int completionDay = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[0]), completionMonth = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[1]), completionYear = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[2]);
    int completionHour = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[0]), completionMinutes = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[1]), completionSeconds = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[2]);
    LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(completionYear, completionMonth, completionDay, completionHour, completionMinutes, completionSeconds);

    LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(7);

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(fromDateTime);

    long days = localDateTime.until(toDateTime, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    long minutes = localDateTime.until(toDateTime, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    long seconds = localDateTime.until(toDateTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    countdownTimePlaceholder = days + "d" + minutes + "m" + seconds + "s";

    return countdownTimePlaceholder;
```

How could I do it better or make it get the remaining time correctly?
Regards.

Comment: You could do better by storing your data in a from that doesn’t require 20 lines to even _parse_. If you stored the completion time as an `Instant` you could trivially use `Duration.between`. Have a look at `MessageFormat` with a choice pattern for the formatting itself.

Answer (score 2):

## Date-time handling is tricky

You said:

> I have never worked with dates and times, this would be my first time.

Date-time handling is surprisingly difficult and confusing. Be patient, study well, and run experiments.

Search Stack Overflow, as your issues have already been addressed many times. I’ll try to be brief here. Search to learn more and see more code examples.

## Store date-time objects

As commented by [Boris The Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70318943/get-hours-minutes-and-seconds-correctly/70319019#comment124303899_70318943), use *java.time* to store your date-time values rather than repeatedly parsing their textual representation.

Or is `QuestProperties` outside your control?

If outside your control, at least simplify your parsing code. Change this:

```
int completionDay = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[0]), completionMonth = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[1]), completionYear = Integer.parseInt(completionDate[2]); 
int completionHour = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[0]), completionMinutes = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[1]), completionSeconds = Integer.parseInt(completionTime[2]);
```

… to this:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( Integer.parseInt(completionDate[2]) , Integer.parseInt(completionDate[1]) , Integer.parseInt(completionDate[0]) ) ;  // year, month, day.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( Integer.parseInt(completionTime[0]) , Integer.parseInt(completionTime[1]) , Integer.parseInt(completionTime[2]) ) ;  // hour, minute, second.
```

## Half-Open

Spans of time are usually best handled using Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a day starts at the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *following* day.

Your code `LocalDateTime.of(2021, 11, 25, 23, 59, 0)` fails to account for the last full minute of the day, the minute between 23:59:00 and 00:00:00.

Change to:

```
LocalDateTime toDateTime = fromDateTime.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay() ;
```

## Time zone

Your biggest problem is that you are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. Getting the date, and determining the first moment of the day time, requires a time zone.

A day ends much earlier in the east than in the west. For example, at some moments, the date can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan  while simultaneously still “yesterday” in Edmonton Canada .

So if you want to run your cooldowns to the end of the day *as seen by the user*, then you must account for the user’s time zone. You can query for their current default time zone. But ultimately best to confirm with the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen in that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

The `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for your needs. That class represents a date and a time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. We used `ZonedDateTime` to represent the current moment with a date, a time-of-day, *and* a time zone.

- `LocalDateTime` =  +
- `ZonedDateTime` =  +  +

Get the first moment of the next day. Notice how we ask *java.time* to determine when the day starts on that date in that zone. Do not assume a day starts at 00:00:00. Days may start at other times.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfTomorrow = zdtNow.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

### Time to elapse

If needed, calculate time to elapse.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtNow , zdtStartOfTomorrow ) ;
```

Compare later moments to see if the deadline has passed.

```
if( ZonedDateTime.now( z ).isAfter( zdtStartOfTomorrow ) ) { … cooldown ended … }
```

### Retrieving moment in UTC

In your case we do not want the current moment. We want to retrieve the user’s moment of last activity from your Quest system.

We parsed need date and the time above, in earlier part of this Answer. But your code did not account for retrieving the time zone. So I will assume the retrieved date and time are as seen « in UTC », with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Adjust that to the user’s desired time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Capturing the current moment

You asked:

> When a challenge is completed I store the date and time it was completed, something like this: 10-12-2021 and 20:33:58.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

To generate text representing that moment for data exchange, call `toString`. For text to present to user, let `DateTimeFormatter` class automatically localize. Both cases have been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much Basil for answering again and clarifying my problem, I have it clearer. I am still in doubt about the WEEKLY type, how can I calculate how many days are left until Thursday and add them up in plusDays.

Comment: @Riardo Regarding weekly, look at how we determined the start of next day. We extracted a `LocalDate` from the starting `ZonedDateTime`. On that `LocalDate` we called the `plusDays` method to add `1` to move to the next day. So, what might we add to move to the next week? In the line `zdtNow.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z )` what should be put in place of that argument `1`?